# Date format with genitive case of the month name is not working

Tags: date-time

Wordpress 4.4 indroduced a way to display the genitive case of a months name for specific locale by using the function `date_i18n` (https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/11226#comment:32) which is filtered by `wp_maybe_decline_date()` (https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.6/src/wp-includes/functions.php#L172). Even though both my locale (el) and the translation of the string "decline months names: on or off" in my el.po file are correct, the genitive case of the months name is not working. So with this: `echo date_i18n( 'j F Y', strtotime( '2016/9/20' ) );` I got the date with the month name in nominative case.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Although, in my wp your `echo` displayed correctly (so maybe double check that you use the correct locale and that "decline months names: on or off" is translated as "on" in your locale), you can *"force"* genitive case, by making a generic wrap function based on the `wp_maybe_decline_date()`.

I have tested and used this, in order to overcome the `wp_maybe_decline_date()` regex that ,matches formats like `'j F Y'` or `'j. F'`, while I wanted to use `'l j F Y'`

Example use case:

In our theme `functions.php` we define the wrapper function like:

```
/**
 * [multi_force_use_genitive_month_date]
 * Call this to force genitive use case for months in date translation
 * @param  string $date Formatted date string.
 * @return string The date, declined if locale specifies it.
 */
function multi_force_use_genitive_month_date( $date ) {
    global $wp_locale;

    // i18n functions are not available in SHORTINIT mode
    if ( ! function_exists( '_x' ) ) {
        return $date;
    }

    /* translators: If months in your language require a genitive case,
     * translate this to 'on'. Do not translate into your own language.
     */
    if ( 'on' === _x( 'off', 'decline months names: on or off' ) ) {
        // Match a format like 'j F Y' or 'j. F'
        $months          = $wp_locale->month;
        $months_genitive = $wp_locale->month_genitive;

        foreach ( $months as $key => $month ) {
            $months[ $key ] = '# ' . $month . '( |$)#u';
        }

        foreach ( $months_genitive as $key => $month ) {
            $months_genitive[ $key ] = ' ' . $month . '$1';
        }

        $date = preg_replace( $months, $months_genitive, $date );
    }

    // Used for locale-specific rules
    $locale = get_locale();

    return $date;
}
```

Then, in our template file where we want the genitive case to appear, we wrap the `date_i18n()`, like:

```
<?php echo multi_force_use_genitive_month_date( date_i18n( 'l j F Y' ) ); ?>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Updated, working version based on the code from @Cubakos:

```
function multi_force_use_genitive_month_date( $date ) {
   global $wp_locale;

   $months          = $wp_locale->month;
   $months_genitive = $wp_locale->month_genitive;

   $date = str_replace( $months, $months_genitive, $date );

   return $date;
}
```

Usage in posts loop

```
<?= multi_force_use_genitive_month_date(get_the_date()); ?>
```

Comment: Please **[edit] your answer**, and add an explanation: **why** does that solve the problem better?

Comment: @Rup yikes, thank for noticing ;)